# Agile Dashboard import error - Tuleap 7.2.99.51

Tags: import

I installed Tuleap to a CentOS 6.5 server following these instructions: http://doc-en.tuleap.net/en/latest/installation-guide/full-installation.html

I had had no issues, I then decided to implement the agile dashboard following these instrctions: http://tuleap-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user-guide/agile-dashboard.html?highlight=agile

I downloaded the tuleap_agiledashboard_template.xml but when I try to import it I get the following error:

**Error Listing**
*src/utils/php-launcher.sh src/utils/import_project_xml.php 101 admin ~/agiledashboard_template.xml*
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/root/agiledashboard_template.xml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/share/tuleap/src/common/project/ProjectXMLImporter.class.php on line 45

Warning: file_get_contents(/root/agiledashboard_template.xml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/share/tuleap/src/common/project/ProjectXMLImporter.class.php on line 45
PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::loadXML(): Empty string supplied as input in /usr/share/tuleap/src/common/project/ProjectXMLImporter.class.php on line 62

Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Empty string supplied as input in /usr/share/tuleap/src/common/project/ProjectXMLImporter.class.php on line 62
*** ERROR: String could not be parsed as XML
[root@tuleap-alm-server codendi]# src/utils/php-launcher.sh src/utils/import_project_xml.php 101 admin /home/root/agiledashboard_template.xml
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/home/root/agiledashboard_template.xml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/share/tuleap/src/common/project/ProjectXMLImporter.class.php on line 45

Warning: file_get_contents(/home/root/agiledashboard_template.xml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/share/tuleap/src/common/project/ProjectXMLImporter.class.php on line 45
PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::loadXML(): Empty string supplied as input in /usr/share/tuleap/src/common/project/ProjectXMLImporter.class.php on line 62

Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Empty string supplied as input in /usr/share/tuleap/src/common/project/ProjectXMLImporter.class.php on line 62
*** ERROR: String could not be parsed as XML

Kind regards
Dennis

Comment: I'm not really sure what is going on in your question. Can you clean it up and make it more readable?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to import the XML directly from the web interface in Agile Dashboard admin

Comment: I fixed the typo

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you run ' yum install  tuleap-plugin-agiledashboard '
and go to agile Dashboard admin import the XML directly.